# C#. ScriptEngine Как создать... перечисление типов наверное

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, комьюнити!

Простите за такое название вопроса, я просто не знаю как его схормулировать. У меня возникла потребность обеспечить возможность исполнения скриптов IronRuby и IronPython в моей программе, м.б. и другие языки добавлю, не знаю. Ну, не спрашивайте зачем мне это, нужно, вот и всё :)

А задача, над которой я думаю, состоит вот в чем: нашел в интернетах способ запуска интерпретируемых языков прямо в C# приложении, на примере IronPython:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("y", yNumber);
engine.ExecuteFile("D://hello2.py", scope);
dynamic xNumber = scope.GetVariable("x");
dynamic zNumber = scope.GetVariable("z");
Console.WriteLine("Сумма {0} и {1} равна: {2}", xNumber, yNumber, zNumber);
```

Но в моей программе заранее не известно, что за скрипт будет использоваться, поэтому я хочу заменить

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
```

на что-то типа

```
ScriptEngine engine = EngineSelector.GetEngine(scriptExt).CreateEngine();
```

Но как мне "сохранить" типы? Я даже примерно не могу представить куда копать, да и возможно-ли такое? Пробовал

```
Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine> EngineSelector = new Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine>();
```

но не вышло. Благодарю за то, что хотя-бы прочли :)

UPD#1
Ошибка при использовании Dictionary<>

https://yadi.sk/i/H-TQCdxStZe88

> Ошибка    CS1061  'ScriptEngine" не содержит определения для
>   "CreateEngine" и не удалось найти метод расширения "CreateEngine",
>   принимающий тип "ScriptEngine" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно,
>   пропущена директива using или ссылка на
>   сборку).

UPD#2

Для Ruby всё также ScriptEngine engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
Можно сделать так:

```
Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine> EngineSelector = new Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine>();
EngineSelector.Add(".py", Python.CreateEngine());
EngineSelector.Add(".rb", Ruby.CreateEngine());
```

Но ведь тогда в Dictionary будут храниться уже объекты, которые занимают память, так ведь?

UPD#3

Но разве это эффективно?

```
    private void RunScript(string ScriptFilename)
    {
        Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine> EngineSelector = new Dictionary<string, ScriptEngine>();
        EngineSelector.Add(".py", Python.CreateEngine());
        EngineSelector.Add(".rb", Ruby.CreateEngine());

        ScriptEngine engine = EngineSelector[Path.GetExtension(ScriptFilename)];
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.ExecuteFile(ScriptFilename, scope);
    }
```

Comment: А почему не вышло? Как вы пробовали? Dictionary — правильное решение.

Comment: Мне VS сообщает об шибке 
https://yadi.sk/i/H-TQCdxStZe88

'ScriptEngine" не содержит определения для "CreateEngine" и не удалось найти метод расширения "CreateEngine", принимающий тип "ScriptEngine" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Отлично, так лучше. Сейчас соображу, как лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<ScriptEngine>> EngineSelector =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<ScriptEngine>>()
{
    { ".py", Python.CreateEngine },
    { ".rb", Ruby.CreateEngine }
};

ScriptEngine engine = EngineSelector[".py"]();
```

Comment: Я сделал почти также (добавил в вопрос). Тут получается хранится указатель на функцию? Или как правильно сказать?

Comment: @demol0cv: Да, это как бы указатель на функцию (в C# это называется _делегат_). Таким образом у вас нету в памяти созданного объекта.

Comment: @demol0cv: Ну и Dictionary нажно создавать один раз, в начале программы, а не при выполнении каждого скрипта.

Comment: Ну, эта функция лишь для тестов, потому и в её теле Dictionary объявляется